# pointer to struct of non-pointer variables. where're these variables, heap or stack?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers

suppose for example this `struct` :

```
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and I declared a pointer to this struct:

```
Point* p;
```

where're x and y of that `p`, heap or stack?

and Is that the same for classes?

Comment: "heap" and "stack" aren't things that you should be thinking about. This question is the perfect argument why those are unhelpful concepts.

Comment: There's no such thing as "heap" or "stack" in the context in which you're trying to use it

Comment: @P0W: Nor is there even an *object* of type `Point`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where're `x` and `y` of that `p`, heap or stack?

Nowhere. You haven't created an object, just a pointer that could point to one.

If you create an automatic object on the stack, then that's where it will be:

```
Point point;
Point * p = &point;
```

If you create a dynamic object on the heap (officially called the *free store*), then that's where it will be:

```
Point * p = new Point; // Don't forget to delete it.
```

> Is that the same for classes?

Yes; a `struct` is a class.

Comment: You might mention static objects as well.  (There's also a special area where exceptions live; `p` could potentially point there as well.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I might, but his introductory text book should cover that better than I could.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question depends on what `p` points to. If it points to a stack-allocated structures, then `p->x` and `p->y` are on the stack. If it was obtained with `new` (or `malloc`), then they are on the heap.

Unlike some other languages, there is no difference in layout of C++ classes and structs. The difference between them is only in in default access restrictions: `class` members are private by default, while `struct` members are public.

Comment: Or none of them, on an implementation that has no stack nor heap.

Comment: What it was obtained with `int main() { char buf[1000]; Point *er = new (buf) Point; }`? Where is `er->x`? What if we have `new (global_storage) Point`?

Comment: @KerrekSB It's still on the stack, placement `new` notwithstanding.

Comment: But that's contradicting your "if it was obtained with `new`"...

Comment: @H2CO3 An implementation always has a "stack" and a "heap" of some sort (one stack per thread, even); the semantics of C++ require it.  On the other hand, if `p` points to a static variable, it will be neither on the heap nor on the stack.

Comment: @KerrekSB Of course it is, but it's a technicality. I could have excluded placement `new`, but I didn't, because the OP is obviously a beginner.

Comment: so if I make a linked list of node `struct node{int data; node* next;};`, all the data would be on the stack?!!

Comment: @JamesKanze I've programmed AVRs in C and C++. They have no heap.

Comment: @TitoTito The data would be where you put it. A linked list would obviously use `new` to create new nodes, and thus such pointers would typically point to heap-allocated data. Storage is the property of the object, not of the pointer pointing to it.

Comment: @H2CO3 Technically, it isn't C++, then, since even a free-standing implementation is required to support `new`.  (Although I wonder.  Would `void* operator new() { throw std::bad_alloc(); }` suffice as a conformant implementation.)  In practice, I expect a lot of compilers for embedded systems have options to support only a subset.

Comment: @JamesKanze Um, I didn't say it didn't support `new` and `malloc()`. It did. I wrote that AVRs don't have a heap.

Comment: @H2CO3 Whatever `malloc` and `new` return pointers to is on the heap.

Comment: @JamesKanze Please quote me the section in the C++ Standard that proves that assertion.

Comment: @H2CO3 It has nothing to do with the C++ standard: it's the (usual) definition of the word heap in this context.  The heap is where dynamic memory comes from (where ever that may be).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you initialize `p`.  The variables `x` and `y` are in whatever `p` points to: if that is on the heap, they are on the heap; if it is on the stack, they are on the stack, and if `p` points to a static variable, they are neither.

Forget about heap and stack: those are implementation details for the compiler.  What you're interested in is not where the bits are located, but the lifetime they might have.

And C++ doesn't really have structs: regardless of the keyword used (`struct`, `class` or `union`), what is declared is a class type.  (Class types can be divided into two large categories, unions and non-union class types.)